# Mismatch between answer counts on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I was viewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20022108/899126) question in the Android app. As shown in the below screenshot, while the top shows "4 answers", the bottom button will ask to "View 6 Answers". After checking the question, there are indeed six answers to the aforementioned question.

[image]

I am using Android 4.3 with the 0.1.64 version of the app.

---

**EDIT**: The changes to the UI made this question obsolete.

Comment: And this is repeatable? If you go there now, you still see it? Because for me it says 6 at the top. And I have a sneaking suspicion you might have gone there around the time that the last 2 answers were posted.

Comment: With this particular question, no (both showed 6 answers). However, I was able to find another question that exhibited the exact same behavior. I couldn't screencap it though, as the app crashed a few seconds later.

Comment: @Bart - Ah, so the number of answers that show up in that top part may be cached on a different time period than the other?

Comment: That is my hunch yes. The answer is always "caching" after all. ;)

Comment: Always, always caching! It's just odd; I would have thought that the two would read from the same field!

Comment: Now that the question/answer interface has been replaced, this is no longer an issue.